# state in my react app get set to undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, jsx

Below is my code for a personal project where i can keep track of my monthly subscriptions, if i have to add a subscription i just have a add an object to an existing array. however for testing purposes when i tried to console.log(value.startDate) in handleSubmit it gives me undefined and causes further problems. How would i fix it?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const List = () => {
    const [ mylist, setList ] = React.useState([]);
    const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState({ subscription: '', startDate: '', paymentTime: 0 });
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log(value.startDate);
        setList(mylist.push(value));
        e.preventDefault();
    };
    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        setValue({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="for_list">
                <ul className="list">{mylist.map((obj) => <li key={obj.subscription}>{obj.subscription}</li>)}</ul>
            </div>
            <div className="for_form">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="subscription" onChange={handleOnChange} value={value.subscription} />
                    <input type="text" name="startDate" onChange={handleOnChange} value={value.startDate} />
                    <input type="number" name="paymentTime" onChange={handleOnChange} value={value.paymentTime} />
                </form>
            </div>
            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
    );
};
// it just removes the error above.
List.propTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.node
};
export default List;
```

Comment: Don't mutate lists and objects that are part of your state.

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing your `state` every time. This might be because of the miss in understanding the difference between `setState` in traditional `class` based `React components` and `useState`.

You need to append the value to the existing data. Something similar would work

```
const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setValue({ ...value, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};
```

The `setState` in `class` based components always accepts `partial` state and merges with the existing one. While `useState` `setter` function replaces the value you provide in the respective state.

Answer (score 1):

On `handleChange` function you need to pass the old value of `value`

```js
 const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setValue({ ...value , [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
 };
```